# onclick em um iframe

Tags: javascript

Boa Tarde!

Bom estou tentando por onclick para fazer o banner sumir quando clicar nele, mas não estou conseguindo !
Meu código:

```
 <div id="mime">
      <iframe style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:605px; height:250px; float:left;" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" src="http://migre.me/pWQGp"></iframe></div>

    <script>
    var div = document.getElementById('mime');
    div.style.display = 'none';

    // Mostra a div após 1 minuto
    setTimeout(function() {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }, 60000);

    </script>
```

Já tentei:

```
      <div id="mime">
        <iframe style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:605px; height:250px; float:left;" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" src="http://migre.me/pWQGp" onClick="OcultarDiv();" style="cursor: pointer;"></iframe>
    </div>
<script>
var div = document.getElementById('mime');
div.style.display = 'none';

// Mostra a div após 1 minuto
setTimeout(function () {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}, 1);

 function OcultarDiv(){  // função ocultar
    div.style.display = "none";
 }
</script>
```

Tentei vários outros codigos, mas não tenho nenhum resultado!
Porfavor me ajudem !
(Sou iniciante em javascript, não sei quase nada, mas estou aprendendo !)

Answer (score 1):

A iFrame apesar de estar na tua página é um elemento externo e o *onclick* não funciona como esperado. Os eventos disparados nessa página pertencem a ela e não podem ser manipulados fora delA. Casi de excepção é se a iFrame estiver no mesmo domínio.

Mas se queres saber quando a iFrame foi clicada podes usar esta ideia:

cria uma nova div que tem posição e dimensões iguais à div que tem a iFrame. Dá-lhe `position: absolute;` e `z-index` maior que a da iFrame para conseguires que ela esteja por cima da outra. Aí podes oscultar eventos sobre essa div e o utilizador não repara.

Nota que nesse caso o utilizador não pode clicar na publicidade do banner, e isso não é muito correto para com o anunciante...

```
var frameDiv = document.getElementById('mime');
var filterDiv = document.getElementById('filtro');
filterDiv.style.zIndex = 100;
filterDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
    frameDiv.style.display = 'none';
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfe7vzcr/

Comment: Sergio, tentei com esse codigo, mas não consegui ! Print de como ficou meu site: http://prntscr.com/7e88wy , o que pode ser isso ?

Comment: @AlexSiqueira tens um link para esse site?

Comment: @Segio redeselect.org/trexs , sergio você teria algum outro meio de comunicação para poder me ajudar melhor ? Skype , facebook... ?

Comment: @AlexSiqueira a ideia deste site é partilhar conhecimentos aqui e nõ em canais privados. Vi o teu site mas não vi a implementação do meu código. Essa ideia de ter um anuncion que segue o mouse não é muito simpática :)

Comment: Bom a ideia do anuncio seguir o mouse é para ter mais cliques, estou tentando fazer uma especie de esquema de cliques. Acabei de colocar seu código no meu site : http://redeselect.org/trexs/ , Como pode ver nem o setTime  de 1 minuto funcionou, nem o "seguir o mouse" :/

Comment: @AlexSiqueira confesso não perceber o que queres fazer. Dizes que queres esconder o iFrame após o clique, mas o iframe segue o mouse obrigando a clicar? então queres __forçar__ que alguém clique de x em x tempo? isso não é muito simpático.

Comment: Sim é exatamente isso, quando a pessoa clicar na publicidade ela automaticamente se esconde!

Comment: @AlexSiqueira acho que não percebeste parte da minha resposta. Se queres clicar na iFrame esse clique não vai ser ouvido pela página mãe e não há como saber que a iFrame foi clicada e então não dá para a esconder. Se quiseres fazer a ideia que eu sugeri com a nova `div#filtro` em cima da iFrame, então não vai ser possível clicar no anuncio artificialmente. Acho que estás num beco sem saída. Acho também pessoalmente que obrigar a clicar dessa forma é má prática.